# How to take an object value by Its ID selected in mat-select and set the object values into a reactive form?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material, frontend

I have a `mat-select` with  a list of `mat-option`, but I have 3 informations in each `mat-option`. Example:

```
<mat-select [(value)]="accountSelected">
   <mat-option [value]="account" *ngFor="let account of listOfAccounts"> 
         Account {{account.accountNumber}} Agency {{account.agencyNumber}} Digit {{account.digitNumber}} 
   </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

But i need to set the value selected in 3 different fields of a form (account, agency, digit), I couldn't find a way to let it reactive as if I was using a form control directly. I thought of using its ID, but I don't know how.

Comment: Check the example: https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview#select-form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<mat-select [(value)]="accountSelected">
   <mat-option [value]="account" *ngFor="let account of listOfAccounts" (click)="yourFunction(account)"> 
         Account {{account.accountNumber}} Agency {{account.agencyNumber}} Digit {{account.digitNumber}} 
   </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

You need add (click)="YourFunction(x)" after *ngFor.
You can create a function like this:

```
yourFunction(x: any): void {console.log(x);}
```

Now you have the object in "x"

Comment: Thanks man! It helped me a lot, but I still got a problem...Is there a way to set the select null so the user MUST "re-select" an option?

Comment: Like a form.reset() I mean...